# Do we have that $\mu(\{0\}) = 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

> Assume $\mu$ is a finite measure on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that$$f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x + t)\,\mu(dt), \quad \text{a.e.,}$$whenever $f$ is real-valued, bounded, and integrable. Show that $\mu(\{0\}) = 1$.

**Thoughts.** Take $f(x) = 1_{|x| < \epsilon}$ and $x = 0$, we get that $\mu((-\epsilon, \epsilon)) = 1$? I am not sure if this is rigorous/how to conclude, could anybody help me out?

Comment: Try something more direct - let $f$ be the indicator function of $\{0\}$.

Comment: What is this notation $\mu(dt)?$ I keep seeing it on MSE and have seen it nowhere else.

Comment: @zhw. Most likely, it denotes integration against the measure $\mu$ in the variable $t$, to remove ambiguity since there are two variables under the integral sign. But I think it's less common notation than, say, $d\mu(t)$.

Comment: Why has this question so many upvotes...? (This question was asked on MSE quite recently, and someone suggested to take $f(x) = 1_{|x|<\epsilon}$; I suspect the OP simply deleted the old question and posted it again ... claiming this suggestion as his "own thoughts".)

Comment: The identity in the question ist supposed to hold "a.e.". Is that to be interpreted as $\mu $-a.e. or as Lebesgue a.e.? If $\mu $-a.e., then also $\mu\equiv 0$ is possible.

Comment: @GyuEunLee How does one conclude that this identity holds there? It seems like showing $\mu \{0\} > 0$ is the only way, but I don't see any obvious way this is true.

Comment: @3-in-441 Ah, fair point.

Comment: @saz I was not aware of this and I upvoted. Now I voted to close.